# Firebase onMessageReceived is triggering twice

Tags: android, .net, vb.net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am scheduling a notification to be launched when a message is received by the Firebase service but the problem that the notification is triggering twice(once on time and second time after maybe 30 min) here is my code:

```
 sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int hour=sharedPreferences.getInt("Hour",9);
        int min=sharedPreferences.getInt("Min",0);
        Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);



        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntent);
```

This is the MyAlarmService onStartCommand:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Figures");
        mBuilder.setContentText("New Figures has been updated!");
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setSound(uri);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(LoginActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

And here is Vb.net sending notification Function:

```
Private Function sendNotification() As Integer
    Try
        Dim url As String = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        Dim tRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

        tRequest.Method = "post"
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        Dim data = New With { _
            Key .[to] =myTopic, _
                Key .TTL = "109", _
            Key .data = New With { _
                Key .body = "Updated", _
                Key .title = "Daily" _
            } _
        }
        Dim jssons As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
        Dim bytearray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jssons)
        tRequest.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: key={0}", MyKey))
        tRequest.Headers.Add(String.Format("Sender: id={0}", MySenderId))
        tRequest.ContentLength = bytearray.Length
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        Using datastream As Stream = tRequest.GetRequestStream()
            datastream.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length)

            Using tresponse As WebResponse = tRequest.GetResponse

                Using dataStreamResponse As Stream = tresponse.GetResponseStream()

                    Using tReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStreamResponse)

                        Dim sResponseFromServer As String = tReader.ReadToEnd()

                        Log(sResponseFromServer, w)
                    End Using
                End Using

            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As WebException
        Log(ex.Message, w)
        Return ex.Status



    End Try
    Log("Notification sent", w)
    Return 200

End Function
```

is there any better way to send the notification?, is there any problem within the AlarmManager?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return START_NOT_STICKY from MyAlarmService.onStartCommand() instead of calling the super method. The super method returns START_STICKY, which will restart your service after it gets killed by the system, re-triggering the notification.

The other question is whether using a service for this is a good idea in general. I'd try a BroadcastReceiver, that won't keep running after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be Ok. But according to the documentation:

> A common scenario for triggering an operation outside the lifetime of your app is syncing data with a server. This is a case where you might be tempted to use a repeating alarm. But if you own the server that is hosting your app's data, using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) in conjunction with sync adapter is a better solution than AlarmManager. A sync adapter gives you all the same scheduling options as AlarmManager, but it offers you significantly more flexibility. For example, a sync could be based on a "new data" message from the server/device (see Running a Sync Adapter for details), the user's activity (or inactivity), the time of day, and so on. See the linked videos at the top of this page for a detailed discussion of when and how to use GCM and sync adapter.

Source: [Scheduling Repeating Alarms documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#tradeoffs)

Maybe you could try using the Sync adapter. Also check if you are receiving the notification twice (I think you are not). Or check if the Alarm is set to a repeting period of 30mins.

Hope this helps.