# google cloud function sends duplicate notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have a gcf that sends a notification for a topic, I trigger the function from an admin android app.
Everything was working as expected, but suddenly the function send the notification two times, sometimes three times.
the function log on google cloud shows the function is sent one notification
it prints only one line of :

> Successfully sent custom

But the Android app receives more than one notification because the `onMessageReceived` is triggered more than once. also, I noticed when the function sent more than one notification the execution time was always more than 15 seconds, and when it sends one notification the execution time was no more than 3 seconds

this is the function's code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const {getMessaging} = require("firebase-admin/messaging");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mylinktodatabase.firebaseio.com",
});

exports.callNotification = functions.https.onCall( (data) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const indicator = data.indicator;
  const mTitle = data.title;
  const mBody = data.body;
  // topic to send to
  const topic = "mytopic";
  const options = {
    "priority": "high",
    "timeToLive": 3600,
  };
  let message;
  if (indicator != null ) {
    message = {
      data: {
        ind: indicator,
      },
    };
  } else {
    message = {
      data: {
        title: mTitle,
        body: mBody,
      },
    };
  }

  // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
  return getMessaging().sendToTopic(topic, message, options)
      .then(() => {
        if (indicator != null ) {
          console.log("Successfully sent message");
          return {
            result: "Successfully sent message", status: 200};
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully sent custom");
          return {
            result: "Successfully sent custom", status: 200};
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (indicator != null ) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
          return {result: `Error sending message: ${error}`, status: 500};
        } else {
          console.log("Error sending custom:", error);
          return {result: `Error sending custom: ${error}`, status: 500};
        }
      });
});
```

this is the image that shows the execution time, notice when it is more than 3 seconds I confirm it sends more than one notification.
[image]

Function gen is 1.
sorry to ask this question here, but google support needs money to answer which is outrageous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase onMessageReceived is triggering twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116761/firebase-onmessagereceived-is-triggering-twice)

Comment: thanks for your comment, no it does not

Comment: The Android app has the problem, which you're ignoring... unless the function indeed runs twice.

Comment: the question you were pointing at as duplicated is not the same function type. also, I included the execution functions time just to show the case the function takes a long time to execute when it sends more than one notification. The android app has nothing to do. because if the android app is the problem it would be 2 instances of the function. in my case, it is one function and I don't have the function's instance limit. it can scale as much as the request are.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Firebase support team.

Functions aim to be “at least once”, multiple executions for a single event is expected behavior and not a bug, in this case, you may try to apply the following recommendations:

1. Write Idempotent Functions (this is the key point) , an idempotent function is it where its
   result is the same if the function is executed once, or more than
   once.
2. Use “context.eventId”, since multiple executions will have the same
   eventId if it resulted from the same event
3. You can check for the logs of a specific event id in the Firebase
   Logs Viewer or Google cloud log to make sure it was the same event.